# Rbinding large list of dataframes after I did some data cleaning on the list

Tags: r, rbind

My problem is, that I can't merge a large list of dataframes before doing some data cleaning. But it seems like my data cleaning is missing from the list.

I have 43 xlsx-files, which I've put in a list.

Here's my code for that part:

```
file.list <- list.files(recursive=T,pattern='*.xlsx')

dat = lapply(file.list, function(i){
    x = read.xlsx(i, sheet=1, startRow=2, colNames = T,
            skipEmptyCols = T, skipEmptyRows = T)

# Create column with file name  
x$file = i

# Return data
x
})
```

I then did some datacleaning. Some of the dataframes had some empty columns that weren't skipped in the loading and some columns I just didn't need.

Example of how I removed one column (X1) from all dataframes in the list:

```
dat <- lapply(dat, function(x) { x["X1"] <- NULL; x })
```

I also applies column names:

```
colnames <- c("ID", "UDLIGNNR","BILAGNR", "AKT", "BA",
          "IART", "HTRANS", "DTRANS", "BELOB", "REGD",
          "BOGFD", "AFVBOGFD", "VALORD", "UDLIGND", 
          "UÅ", "AFSTEMNGL", "NRBASIS", "SPECIFIK1",
          "SPECIFIK2", "SPECIFIK3", "PERIODE","FILE")
dat <- lapply(dat, setNames, colnames)
```

My problem is, when I open the list or look at the elements in the list, my data cleaning is missing.

And I can't bind the dataframes before the data cleaning since they're aren't looking the same.

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT: Sample data***

```
# Sample data
a <- c("a","b","c")
b <- c(1,2,3)
X1 <- c("", "","")
c <- c("a","b","c")
X2 <- c(1,2,3)
X1 <- c("", "","")
df1 <- data.frame(a,b,c,X1)
df2 <- data.frame(a,b,c,X1,X2)

# Putting in list
dat <- list(df1,df2)

# Removing unwanted columns
dat <- lapply(dat, function(x) { x["X1"] <- NULL; x })
dat <- lapply(dat, function(x) { x["X2"] <- NULL; x })

# Setting column names
colnames <- c("Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma")
dat <- lapply(dat, setNames, colnames)

# Merging dataframes 
df <- do.call(rbind,dat)
```

So I've just found that with my sample data this goes smoothly. 
I had to reopen the list in View-mode to see the changes I made. That doesn't change the fact that when writing to csv and reopening all the data cleaning is missing (haven'tr tried this with my sample data).

I am wondering if it's because I've changed the merge?

```
# My merge when I wrote this question: 
df <- do.call("rbindlist", dat)

# My merge now: 
df <- do.call(rbind,dat)
```

When I use my real data it doesnøt go as smoothly, so I guess the sample data is bad. I don't know what I'm doing wrong so I can't give some better sample data.

The message I get when merging with rbind:

```
error in rbind(deparse.level ...) numbers of columns of arguments do not match
```

Comment: Can you share a minimal reproducible example? Two or three dataframes with a couple of columns each? Share the output of `dput(lapply(dat[1:3], function(x) head(x[1:5])))` if that is enough to be representative.

Comment: Which part of the data cleaning process is missing? It doesn't have a filename? or it doesn't remove columns or names are not being applied?

Comment: All of my datacleaning is missing from the elements within the list. 

I'll try and see if I can make some sample data that'll work

Comment: This is very weird.. with my sample data everything goes smoothly..

Comment: You could use readxl::read_xlsx for excel reading and dplyr::bind_rows for merging. Usually better and faster alternatives to what you are doing. Don't use variable name colnames as it is a function name in base. Also you are now naming the dataframes, not the columns in the dataframes. Use `dat <- lapply(dat, function(df){names(df)<- my_names; df})` instead

Comment: @Probel I'll try and use that load next time - right now I have it in my environment, and it takes so long to reload ;) About the colnames... I tried doing that, however corrected "df" to "dat", since df doesn't exist at the time I add colnames. It wass much slower and the result is the samne

Comment: I've edited the question with my error message. I get: `error in rbind(deparse.level ...) numbers of columns of arguments do not match`. When I View the dat list, they all have the same 22 columns so I really don't get this

Comment: @LouiseSørensen `df` is a variable name in the lambda function. It does not have to exist in the global environment. You were right about the setNames although using `colnames` as variable name is still bad practice. Try using `dplyr::bind_rows` for merging since it will pad with NA any column that does not exist in some of the dataframes. Then you will see what the problem is. And about the long loading: it does not take that long with `readxl::read_xlsx`, the time it takes is a fraction of `read.xlsx` :)

Comment: When I use `dplyr::bind_rows` I get `Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) :  Column SPECIFIK1 can't be converted from numeric to character`. Now this is a text column so it's weird

Comment: OK. So I've tried to use `read_xlsx` as suggested. Still takes a while since my data is 1,3 GB when uploaded in R. Not sure if it was quicker..Then I did my data cleaning and then as suggested: `df <- do.call(dplyr::bind_rows, dat)`. And I get the same message - that one of my columns can't be converted from character to numeric. Why is it trying to convert my columns?

Comment: I think my problem is that my columns don't have the same classes... I just don't know how to changes column classes on a list of data frames

Comment: Ok. So I ended up opening all 43 xlsx files and deleting the columns, since R kept not working and I'm short on time.. Then loaded them into a list with the function above with `read_xlsx`. Then added colnames (and called my colnames `my_names` insted of colnames. The I converted all columns to character since R keeps having trouble with the binding (apparantely come of the xlsx files they are numeric and in other text). I did this with `dat <- lapply(dat, function(x) { x["ID"] <- as.character(x["ID"]); x })`.

Comment: Then I merged the dataframes in the list with first `bind_rows` as suggested. That didn't work. The data looked weird (will get back to this). Then with `"rbindlist"` as in my code above. That took forever so I terminated. Then with `rbind` and it looked like with the `bind_rows`. When I View the data all column names looks right. But the data is missing (it seems like). I do have a lot of observations according to my environment. And when I do `str(df)` It looks like this: `Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 6565685 obs. of  16 variables:`

Comment: My structure shows up like this: `$ ID    : chr "c(123456789, 124759606 (...)`. It's a mess and not a list as I'm used to. @Probel do you know what I'm doing wrong here? Please refer to my last 3 comments (including this one)

Comment: hi @LouiseSørensen maybe SO is not the right place to debug this, it's not a general problem but a very specific one related to your files and what exactly you are doing. maybe if you have some friend who knows r who could help you irl, or hit me up in this ad hoc chat room and we can see if we can solve it quick:) https://tlk.io/r_problem_adhoc_chat

Comment: Thanks, but I ended up solving it. Solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54591376/binding-dataframes-in-list-after-data-cleaning-on-list

The problem wasn't about my data, but the way I cleaned my data :)