# Binding dataframes in list after data cleaning on list

Tags: r, merge, rbind, rbindlist

This is a follow up on my last question ([Rbinding large list of dataframes after I did some data cleaning on the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54569448/rbinding-large-list-of-dataframes-after-i-did-some-data-cleaning-on-the-list)). I've gotten smarter and the former question got messy.

I have 43 xlsx files which I loaded in to a list in R:

```
file.list <- list.files(recursive=T,pattern='*.xlsx')

dat = lapply(file.list, function(i){
x = read_xlsx(i, sheet=1, col_names = T)

# Create column with file name  
x$file = i
# Return data
x
})
```

I then added some column names:

```
my_names <- c("ID", "UDLIGNNR","BILAGNR", "AKT", "BA",
          "IART", "HTRANS", "DTRANS", "BELOB", "REGD",
          "BOGFD", "VALORD", "UDLIGND", 
          "UÅ", "AFSTEMNGL", "NRBASIS","FIBILAG", "FILE")
dat <- lapply(dat, setNames, my_names)
```

Then I removed some columns:

```
dat <- lapply(dat, function(x) { x["UÅ"] <- NULL; x })
dat <- lapply(dat, function(x) { x["FIBILAG"] <- NULL; x })
```

I don't really need to remove them, but when I tried to merge the dataframes I kept getting errors about the class of these. So I just removed them.

Then I changes all my columns to character. I'm kinda new to R, so I'm aware that this code isn't very sexy and you probably could have made a loop or just one function for this. But this is what I did:

```
dat <- lapply(dat, function(x) { x["ID"] <- as.character(x["ID"]); x })
```

[I did the same for all columns]

And then I go and bind the data.

```
df <- rbindlist(dat)
```

**EDIT:**

I've found that it isn't my binding methods that's the problem (thank you for your inputs on that). I've deleted the part about the binding methods.

The problem lies in how I change the coltypes on my columns in my dataframes within the list.

I've also tried:

```
    dat <- lapply(dat, function(x) { x[,"ID"] <- as.character(x[,"ID"]); x })
```

I added a comma before "ID". This didn't help. I feel like I need to use unlist, but I'm not sure how to use it here?

Comment: You don't need `do.call(rbindlist`, it would be `rbindlist(dat)`.  Regarding the other part of the code `dat[] <- lapply(dat, function(x) setDT(dat)[, (my_names) := lapply(.SD, as.character), .SDcols = my_names])`

Comment: When I use `dat[] <- lapply(dat, function(x) setDT(dat)[, (my_names) := lapply(.SD, as.character), .SDcols = my_names])` my list of data frames is converted to a data frame with 18 observations (my 18 columns in each data frame) and 43 columns (I have 43 data frames in the list).

Comment: sorry, there is a code typo, I meant `setDT(x)`

Comment: Ok, now it says it's a list with a list with a dataframe of 18 x 43. When using your suggested rbindlist I get df with 18 obs and 43 columns. Seems like there's still something wrong?

Comment: using rbindlist provides the same output as do.call(rbind,dat)

Comment: Should I be using unlist?

Comment: Yes, but I meant that you don't need `do.call`

Comment: Please see my edit to the question - it's not the bind that's the problem, it's the coltypes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of data frames `dat` i would recommend

```
df <- dplyr::bind_rows(dat)
```

to row bind them to one big data frame.

Alternatively you should use the purrr map family and return a row binded data.frame directly?

```
df <- purrr::map_dfr(file.list, function(x) readxl::read_xslx(x))
```

Comment: The purr solution didn't work cause I have a column that is numbers in some of the xlsx files and characters in other, so before merging I need to convert it to character.

Comment: Also readxl::read_xlsx lets you specify the columns type when you parse the columns via the `col_types` argument

Comment: I just tried with read_xlsx - so I deleted my comment again :) I'll try and set colnames, delete columns and then merge with bind_rows to see if it does anything that I skip the data cleaning. Fingers crossed. Data is big, so every try takes a while.

Comment: Ok so now I get the error `Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : 
  Column AKT can't be converted from numeric to character` and I kinda need that column so can't just delete it... I tried the whole column converting (see my code above) and I think maybe that's where the mistake is... Do you think I should be using unlist in my converting to character?

Comment: Please see my edit to the question - it's not the bind that's the problem, it's the coltypes.

Comment: Setting the col_types to "text" or whatever is needed when importing using read_xslx as hinted above. That should take care of incompatible types.

Answer (score 0):

**I found a solution!!**

Thank you for your help!

Apparently the problem wasn't in the binding of the data frames in the nested list. The problem was that I was changing the column types the wrong way.

Here's my code - and it works! And it's super faster than the other one!

```
file.list <- list.files(recursive=T,pattern='*.xlsx')

dat = lapply(file.list, function(i){
x = read_xlsx(i, sheet=1, col_names = T)

# Create column with file name  
x$file = i
# Return data
x
})

# Setting column names
my_names <- c("ID", "UDLIGNNR","BILAGNR", "AKT", "BA",
          "IART", "HTRANS", "DTRANS", "BELOB", "REGD",
          "BOGFD", "VALORD", "UDLIGND", 
          "UÅ", "AFSTEMNGL", "NRBASIS","FIBILAG", "FILE")

dat <- lapply(dat, setNames, my_names)

# Removing problematic columns
dat <- lapply(dat, function(x) { x["UÅ"] <- NULL; x })
dat <- lapply(dat, function(x) { x["FIBILAG"] <- NULL; x })


dat2 <- lapply(dat, function(df) setDT(df)[, (1:16) := lapply(.SD, as.character), .SDcols = 1:16])

# Merging
df <- rbindlist(dat2)
```

Oh and several people told me to use bind_rows instead (@atomman and @Probel)

And I want to give credit to the person whom I stole the first part from, but I can't remember...